# How to include google map in drupal webform using location field in form?

Tags: google-maps, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I created webform with the field location as textbox and map as geofield. I want to pass location value to map field and then according to location it will show the map.
Means Map will take the input as location field value.
Can anyone suggest suitable option to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Would the gmap module help you?

https://drupal.org/project/gmap

As described:
The GMap module provides an interface to the Google Maps API within Drupal. It integrates with the Location module to provide users a clickable map for entering latitude and longitude, as well as to display maps of Drupal nodes and users. GMap can be used to create interactive maps with various map markers and content in map bubbles, taking advantage of Drupal's other content management features. The module also provides a Views display plugin which allows users to display the results of a view on a Google map.